# Saving a list - Windows 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-8, isolatedstorage, application-data

I'm developing the Windows 8 equivalent of [my app](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/knowledge-organizer/611c36ab-db53-40e2-b1b2-043899bbe6bc).

I'm trying to save simple list of strings to ApplicationDataContainer, as I would with IsolatedStorage for Windows Phone 8.

In Windows Phone 8 I would do it like this:

```
List<String> myList;
myList= readSetting("myList") != null ? (List<String>)readSetting("myList") : new List<String>();
```

Helper method:

```
        private static object readSetting(string key)
    {
        return IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains(key) ? IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings[key] : null;
    }
```

But how should I do this in Windows 8? My app is of the type Split Page.

Thanks a lot!

Kind Regards,
Erik

Answer (score 0):

Try using Storage Helpers like [this](https://isolatedstoragew8.codeplex.com/) and [this](https://metrostoragehelper.codeplex.com/). Or you can use `StorageFile` in Windows 8 which allows you read-write files in local folder

Comment: I'll take a look at it when I get time - thanks for you help!:)

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent to IsolatedStorageSettings on Win8 (and WP8) is [ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdatacontainer.aspx)

Create a container

```
var container = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.CreateContainer("defaultContainer",ApplicationDataCreateDisposition.Always);
container.Values["newKey"] = "New Value";
```

Your method would become:

```
private static object readSetting(string key)
{
    var container = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.CreateContainer("defaultContainer",ApplicationDataCreateDisposition.Existing);
    if (container == null)
    {
       return null;
    }
    return Container.Values[key]
}
```

Note that this will also work on Windows Phone 8 if you would like to reuse some code between the two platforms.